# JavaFx GridPane - how to center elements

Tags: java, user-interface, positioning, javafx-2, gridpanel

I have a `GridPane` filled with 1-letter-labels.

Here is an image:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
int charSpacing = 1;
int charsInWidth = 28;
int charsInHeight = 16;

double charWidth = 15;
double charHeight = 20;

GridPane gp = new GridPane();
gp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

Label[] tmp = new Label[charsInHeight*charsInWidth];

String text = "W";
int currArrPos = 0;

for(int y = 0; y < charsInHeight; y++) {
    HBox hbox = new HBox(charSpacing);

    for(int x = 0; x < charsInWidth; x++) {
        tmp[currArrPos] = new Label(text);
        tmp[currArrPos].setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("white"));

        tmp[currArrPos].setMinHeight(charHeight);
        tmp[currArrPos].setMinWidth(charWidth);
        tmp[currArrPos].setMaxHeight(charHeight);
        tmp[currArrPos].setMaxWidth(charWidth);

        tmp[currArrPos].setStyle("-fx-border-color: white;");
        hbox.getChildren().add(tmp[currArrPos++]);

        if(x%2 == 0){
            text = "I";
        } else{
            text = "W";
        }
    }
    gp.add(hbox, 1, y);
}
guiDisplay.getChildren().add(gp);
```

How can I center the characters?

I have put them in a `HBox` and gave them spacing. I tried to make the `textAlignment` of the label to `CENTER`, but that doesn't work of course.

I tried this also:

```
gp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Has anybody an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

oh, that was easy. i did the alignment on the wrong place. adding this will do the job:

```
tmp[currArrPos].setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

thanks anyway.

Comment: `import javafx.geometry.Pos` for those who wondered. Also, why didn't they call it `Position`, as Java would normally do?

Answer (score 29):

- You can use this `GridPane.setHalignment(tmp[currArrPos], HPos.CENTER);`
  [Using GridPane to layout controls](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/UsingGridPanetolayoutcontrols.htm)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `setAligment(Pos.CENTER)` property of your element-

or you can define a `contraint` to the `GridPane` that contains the elements

```
<columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" />
</columnConstraints>
```

Example:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>

<GridPane fx:controller="app.graphics.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" />
    </columnConstraints>
</GridPane>
```