# JavaFX Gridpane Layout with Colspan and Rowspan

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

I'm trying to center a button in JavaFX using Gridpane. I was told to use colspan and rowspan, but I can't figure out how those work.

```
    pane.add(label1, 0, 1);
    pane.add(text1, 1, 1);
    pane.add(radioButton1, 0, 2);
    pane.add(radioButton2, 1, 2);
    pane.add(label2, 0, 3);
    pane.add(text2, 1, 3);
    pane.add(button, 0, 4); //What I'm trying to span.
```

[This is what I have,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa5Dq.png) and [This is where I want the button to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqSOo.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFx GridPane - how to center elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816075/javafx-gridpane-how-to-center-elements)

Comment: Also consider the approach examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31909941/230513), which obviates the need for a calculate button altogether.

Comment: You need to make the button span two columns, and then center it, so it is centered across both columns. Just read the API docs for the method calls.

Answer (score 1):

I originally thought you were trying to center each line. After seeing James_D's comment, it seems that you are only having an issue with the calculate `Button`.

For that try:

```
pane.add(button, 0, 4, 2, 1); //add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int rowspan)
GridPane.setHalignment(button, HPos.CENTER);
```